# If statements into For Loop

Tags: javascript

I spent about an hour last night attempting to transform this unnecessarily complex if statement into a for loop. I got the loop working somewhat previously, but it wouldn't update the .src for various strings.

In theory, I know that this should work given all of the if statements share a lot of similarities, but cannot get a functional version working.

In short, there are two variables at play; `storeInvenLevel` and `inventoryFull`. `storeInveLevel` has a max of 2, while `inventoryFull` has a max of 3. There are three images in the html file under `item_string`, `item2_string` and `item3_string`. When the function is triggered, it should cross-reference `inventoryFull` and replace the last image in the list (if 3, 3. If 2, 2) first. If `storeInvenLevel` = 1, then it should remove 2 (assuming at least 2 are set) at once (or 1 if only 1 is set), and if `storeInveLevel` = 2, it should remove 3 (assuming 3 are set), or 2 or 1, depending on what's set.

Any help is appreciated.

*Note - all variables not defined in the snippet below are just integers.*

```
const item_string = document.getElementById("inventory");
const item2_string = document.getElementById("inventory_2");
const item3_string = document.getElementById("inventory_3");

function removeInventory(){
    if(inventoryFull===1){
        item_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
        inventoryFull--;
        itemSave = item_string.src;
        itemsProcessed++
        gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
    } else if (inventoryFull===2){
        if (storeInvenLevel===2 && inventoryFull===2){
            item_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave = item_string.src;
            item2_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            inventoryFull = inventoryFull-2;
            itemSave2 = item2_string.src;
            itemsProcessed = itemsProcessed+2;
            for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
                gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
            }
            gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
        } else if (storeInvenLevel===1 && inventoryFull===2){
            item_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave = item_string.src;
            item2_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            inventoryFull = inventoryFull-2;
            itemsProcessed = itemsProcessed+2;
            for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
                gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
            }
            itemSave2 = item2_string.src;
        } else if(storeInvenLevel===0 && inventoryFull===2){
            item2_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            inventoryFull--;
            itemsProcessed++
            itemSave2 = item2_string.src;
            gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
        }
    } else if (inventoryFull===3){
        if (storeInvenLevel===2 && inventoryFull===3){
            item_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave = item_string.src;
            item2_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave2 = item2_string.src;
            item3_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave3 = item3_string.src;
            inventoryFull = inventoryFull-3;
            itemsProcessed = itemsProcessed+3;
            for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
                gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
            }
        } else if (storeInvenLevel===1 & inventoryFull===3){
            item2_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave2 = item2_string.src;
            item3_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
            itemSave3 = item3_string.src;
            inventoryFull = inventoryFull-2;
            itemsProcessed = itemsProcessed+2;
            for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
                gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
            }
        } else if (storeInvenLevel===0 & inventoryFull===3){
        item3_string.src = "./images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
        inventoryFull--;
        itemsProcessed++
        itemSave3 = item3_string.src;
        gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:// Original Implementation of Loop

```
function inventoryLoop(){
    var trans = "http://identifyquest.com/images/ItemsCards_transparent/Transparent.gif";
    var y = document.getElementById("inventory_"+inventoryFull);
    var x = 'itemSave'+inventoryFull;

    for(var i=0; i<inventoryFull || i<storeInvenLevel; i++){
        if(inventoryFull===1){
            item_string.src=trans;
            itemSave = item_string.src;
        } else {
            y=trans;
            x=y;
        }
        inventoryFull--;
        itemsProcessed++;
        gold = gold + (1*goldMultipler);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your implementation of loop?

Comment: I'll need to rebuild it, but yes I can :)

Comment: Why would a loop make sense for conditional logic. Loops are for iteration of elements or sequences, not for combinatorial permutations of two variables where each combination has unique logic. I've only glanced at your code... but I see a lot of repetition, and you can remove that with properly structured if-else logic.

Comment: My thinking is that the same loops are being performed, just a different amount of times dependant on certain variables.

Comment: I've put my implementation of the loop in the original post.